# "How do you say that in Russian" is it correct in the following context?

Tags: construction

Many time when my friend talk to me in English and I want to know the parallel word of this English word but in Russian language. So, what is the right why to ask it?

I always say **"How do you say that word in Russian"**. But to me it sounds a little strange and I would like to know the *acceptable sentence* that people used to say in this context

Comment: That's it - a perfectly polite, clear sentence requesting what you're after.  Another common form is, "What is the Russian word for that?"

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think so, nice to know it :)

Answer (score 1):

"How do you say that in Russian?" is fine, but possibly ambiguous. "That" could be either a word, a phrase or a sentence. It might even be a paragraph. If you're on good terms with the Russian speaker, this should not be a problem, since whatever misunderstandings arise can be easily overcome. If you ordinarily want to know just the meaning of a word, you friend will quickly learn that, and assume that you only want to know a word, but will probably have to ask you which word.

If you want to be more precise, you can ask, "What is the Russian word for _____?" or "What is ______ in Russian?".